# Boot2Docker using standard terminal with bash shell and NOT zsh shell with iterm2?

Tags: docker, zsh, boot2docker, iterm2

I just installed Boot2Docker on my OSX and it appears to be working opening it by clicking on the icon loads everything in the bash shell.

I have iterm2 set as my default and inside iterm2 I use zsh.

Anyone know a work around on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use boot2docker, just open your regular terminal and do:

```
$ boot2docker up
$ $(boot2docker shellinit)
```

You should then be able to run regular Docker commands:

```
$ docker run -it supertest2014/nyan
...
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, this is what I needed.